# Form validation: How should I validate one dependent user input with another user input?

Tags: javascript, validation

Thanks for your time. I'll start by saying I'm just beginning my journey in JS and could really use some help here.

I'm trying to leverage JS to validate DOBs for new student enrollment forms in our student information system. In the form, we have a DOB, and GL/Grad. Yr among other fields. What I'd like to do is verify the DOB qualifies for the selected GL.

To make this more dynamic, I'd like to validate with the grad year as it wouldn't have to be changed as often, but the Grad. Yr is calculated from Grade Level and not actually a user-input field.

I have little to no knowledge with JS and would appreciate any direction for some viable code, or even a direction to resources to equip myself with adaptable skillsets, for the future.

Right now, all I've done is prompted an alert at the successful loading on the form but it doesn't actually filter and demand healthy data. Also, I've formatted the fields to be highlighted to make the entry a but more guided, beyond the required fields assigned through the configuration panels.

---

```
document.getElementById('tStateID').style.backgroundColor= "Yellow";
document.getElementById('sGender').style.backgroundColor= "Yellow";
document.getElementById('sEthnicity').style.backgroundColor= "Yellow";
document.getElementById('dBirthdate').style.backgroundColor= "Yellow";
document.getElementById('tBirthCountry').style.backgroundColor= "Yellow";
document.getElementById('tGradYear').style.backgroundColor= "Yellow";
document.getElementById('sState').style.backgroundColor= "Yellow";
document.getElementById('eRace').style.backgroundColor= "Yellow";
document.getElementById('eLanguage').style.backgroundColor= "Yellow";
document.getElementById('eNativeLang').style.backgroundColor= "Yellow";
document.getElementById('eHomeLang').style.backgroundColor= "Yellow"; function checkCountry() {
if (document.getElementById("tBirthCountry").value=="")
    return;

if (document.getElementById("tBirthCountry").value.toUpperCase()=="USA") {
    unFlagAsRequired('tInitUSEnrl','lblInitialUSEnrollment');
    unFlagAsRequired('tNbrMnthNonUSAttn','lblNbrofMnthNonUSAttn');
}
else {
    flagAsRequired('tInitUSEnrl','lblInitialUSEnrollment');
document.getElementById('tInitUSEnrl').style.backgroundColor= "Yellow";
    flagAsRequired('tNbrMnthNonUSAttn','lblNbrofMnthNonUSAttn');
document.getElementById('tNbrMnthNonUSAttn').style.backgroundColor= "Yellow";
}

function unFlagAsRequired(pField,pLabel) {
if (!pField || !pLabel) {
    return;
}

document.getElementById(pLabel).innerHTML = 
document.getElementById(pLabel).innerHTML.replace('*&nbsp;','');

for (var i = 0; i < gExtraValidationField.length; i++) {
    if (gExtraValidationField[i] != "" && typeof(gExtraValidationField[i]) != "undefined") {
        if (gExtraValidationField[i]==pField) {
            gExtraValidationField[i]="";
        }
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < gExtraValidationLabel.length; i++) {
    if (gExtraValidationLabel[i] != "" && typeof(gExtraValidationLabel[i]) != "undefined") {
        if (gExtraValidationLabel[i]==pLabel) {
            gExtraValidationLabel[i]="";

checkCountry();

addEvent(document.getElementById('tBirthCountry'),'change',checkCountry);

flagAsRequired('sGender','lblGender');

flagAsRequired('sEthnicity','lblFederalStateEthnicity');

flagAsRequired('sState','lblStateRace');

flagAsRequired('eRace','lblLocalRace');
```

Comment: Please show the code you've created so far. Are there any restrictions on DOB or do you accept any valid date? What options are valid for Grade Level? Does any of this have to be validated against a database?

Comment: The DOB only limits >1901 and before current date to my knowledge. I wouldn't know how to access the hard code. The GL options are 01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,K,P1,P2,P3,P4. As far as checking against a DB, I don't believe so because it's the first entry. We've already passed a form whereas existing rows in the name table would have been found.

Comment: @eusotech Could you please post the HTML and CSS? If possible, could you create a jsfiddle as well? That will make it much easier for us to help you. Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how to provide that information from within my MGMT system.

Comment: @eusotech I don't see anything in your code about GL. I also don't see your HTML. You're also missing the ``flagAsRequired`` function definition. Without all that relevant info it's difficult, if not impossible, to help you.

Comment: @kmoser I appreciate your clarification, I'll do some more homework and return more prepared.